# Google Endpoint Verification

Tags: java, android, security, verification, endpoint

I'm developing a mobile application that uses Google endpoints (Java) for the back-end.

I'm not certain how Google endpoints prevents spam bots from accessing the endpoint API and making thousands of "Register" requests. How does one fight against this?

Thanks,

-Scott

Answer (score 2):

You can add authentication to your endpoint APIs. THis way, only your app can make the calls. See this for more info: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/clients/android/add_auth_ids

Of course if some hacker knows the URL of your API, then they can still attack it (DOS), but I assume Google's Cloud infrastructure will "help" you if that happens.